# integral found in a moment generating function

Tags: calculus

In Statistics and Data Analysis by Tamhane I found this integral in chapter 2 used for calculating the moments of an exponential function. Can someone explain how this integral works? I don't understand how the 2nd step leads to the last step.

for $ t < \lambda $

$M_x(t) = \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{tx}\lambda e^{-\lambda x}dx$

$ = \lambda \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-(\lambda - t) x}dx$

$ = \frac{\lambda}{\lambda - t}$

Comment: There's a typo: integrand in the second line should be $e^{(t-\lambda)x}$. Now, hint: scalars can be pulled out of integrals, and how do we multiply with exponents with like bases?

Comment: @SeanRoberson There is no typo, the integrand is correct.

Comment: Thanks! I fixed the typo. I get the second step (I saw it as right after I posted the question). The last step, it seems to me should equate to $ \frac{\lambda}{\lambda -t}e^{-(\lambda - t) x}$

Comment: nm. I got it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\lambda$ is a constant, you can take it out from the integral.

Then use exponential properties:

$$\large e^{tx} e^{-\lambda x} = e^{tx - \lambda x} = e^{x(t - \lambda)} = e^{-(\lambda - t)x}$$

Now you can call $\lambda - t = z$ which is a constant and get by elementary analysis

$$\int e^{-zx} dx = -\frac{1}{z}e^{-zx} + C$$

Which in your case becomes

$$\lambda\left(-\frac{1}{\lambda - t} \large e^{-x(\lambda -t)}\bigg|_0^{+\infty}\right) = -\frac{\lambda}{\lambda - t} \left(e^{-\infty(\lambda - t)} - e^{0(\lambda - t)}\right) =  \frac{\lambda}{\lambda - t}$$

For the records: I know that writing $\infty$ is wrong, but in this way the OP will understand better. It's clearly understood that it's a limit, as $x\to +\infty$.

Answer (score 0):

Just compute the integral directly. Compute the antiderivative of the integrand, and so on...
$$\int_0^\infty e^{-(\lambda - t) x} \mathop{dx} = \left[-\frac{1}{\lambda - t} e^{-(\lambda - t)x}\right]_{x=0}^\infty = -\frac{1}{\lambda - t} \left(\lim_{x \to \infty} e^{-(\lambda - t) x} - 1\right) = \frac{1}{\lambda - t}.$$